# Travelling from Auckland to Ho Chi Minh City with Jetstar

Tags: transit, luggage, jetstar

I am travelling on Jetstar from Auckland to Ho Chi Minh City on Sunday 19th April and have only just noticed that I might have to recheck my bag after each leg.  This means rechecking in Melbourne and then again in Singapore.

I checked the website and it stated that international connecting flights might have bags checked all the way through but I can't find this out for certain.  I am concerned about this as I only have 1 hour and 40 mins in Melbourne before my flight to Singapore and I don't think this is enough time.

Any help/advice is gratefully received!

Answer (score 1):

Per the [Jetstar website](http://www.jetstar.com/au/en/planning-and-booking/flight-connections):

> For many bookings we’ll transfer your bags and you won’t need to check
>   in again. They include:
>
> - Connecting international flights

Since Auckland-Melbourne and Melbourne-Singapore are both international, your flights qualify: you do not need to recheck bags or pass through immigration, just proceed directly to your connecting flight.

This is presumably the case for your transit in Singapore as well, assuming you've managed to purchase this as a single ticket.